# Prove that if $c>0, x>0$, and $x^2=c$ then $x $ is unique.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if $c>0, x>0$, and $x^2=c$ then $x$ is unique.

Here is how I start.  Assume $x$ is not unique.  Let, $x>0, y>0$, and $c>0$ such that $x^2=c$ and $y^2=c$.

(1)By the transitive property we have $x^2=y^2$.

(2)Since $x$ and $y$ are positive, taking the square root of both sides we show $x=y$.

(3)Therefore x is unique.

I'm sure step (2) is not valid... Any hints?

Comment: $f(x)=x^n$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$ (and thus injective on $[0,\infty)$) for any $n\in\mathbb N$. In particular for $n=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x^2=y^2$

$(x-y)(x+y)=0$

$x-y=0$ since $x+y>0$

$x=y$

Your argument at 2) is circular (you use as hypothesis that $u^2=v$ has an unique solution; the same thing that you need to prove)

Comment: You're right.  I knew (2) was invalid.  Can't believe I didn't think of this.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I agree that step 2 is not valid.  Here's my approach:

Suppose that "$x$ is not unique".  Then there exist $0<x<y$ with $x^2 = y^2 = c$.  However,
$$
c = x^2 = xx < yx < yy = y^2 = c
$$
But $c<c$ is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

Recall that if $a>b$ and $c$ is a positive number then $ac>bc$.

So now suppose $x\neq y$. Without loss of generality $x>y$.

Therefore $xx>xy>yy$.

We have proven that if $x\neq y$ then $x^2 \neq y^2$ for $x,y$ positive reals. So the contrapositive statement is also true, in other words: if $x^2=y^2$ for positive reals $x,y$ then $x=y$.

Comment: basicallly omnom's approach with more words.

Comment: In order to save some more words (in both answers) and maybe make clearer the key idea of the argument, we could say only that $f (x) = x ^ 2$ is strictly increasing on $ (0, \infty) $.